# Fair queue loses notifications

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, notifications, thread-safety

Consider the following code

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

template <typename T>
class Tqueue 
{
public:

   Tqueue() : m_next_ticket(0),
              m_counter(0) {}

   void push(const T& e){
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
       m_queue.push(e);
       lock.unlock();
       m_cond.notify_all();
    };

   T wait_and_pop() {
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
       int ticket = m_next_ticket++;
       m_cond.wait(lock,[=]{return (!m_queue.empty())
                  && (ticket == m_counter);});
       m_counter++;
       T data = m_queue.front();
       m_queue.pop();
       return data;
   }

private:
   int m_next_ticket;
   int m_counter;
   std::queue<T> m_queue;
   std::mutex m_mutex;
   std::condition_variable m_cond;   
};
```

This should be a template for a fair queue i came up with. Fair in this context means, that wait_and_pop() calls return in the same order they were called by different threads.

For example:
**Thread 1** calls wait_and_pop() on an empty queue and blocks. Then **Thread 2** calls wait_and_pop() on an empty queue and blocks. Afterwards **Thread 3** pushes two events with push(). Now **Thread 1** should return before **Thread 2**.

Using the following code, from time to time it works. But most of the time
the code blocks forever:

```
Tqueue<int> queue;

std::mutex mutex;

void test(int i) 
{
    auto bla = queue.wait_and_pop();
    std::cout << "Thread : "<<bla << std::endl;
}

const int SIZE = 200;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
       threads.push_back(std::thread(test,i));
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        queue.push(i);
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
       threads[i].join();
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is that for each thread an unique ticket is created. Using a conditional variable, we then wait in the wait_and_pop() function until 
an new event is inserted. In the push() function the new event is inserted in the queue and all waiting threads are notified. Each thread checks if 
the queue is not empty anymore and if the unique ticket is equal to the current counter. If so, the particular thread leaves the conditional loop,
pops the current event from the queue and increases the counter.

I suspect, that some notifications are lost but i can't get my head around the fact, why this is happening. Any ideas how to fix this or how one can implement this in the right way?

**EDIT**
I changed the code from the queue as follows. Now it seems to work.
The important part is, that i notifiy, while still holding the lock (in push() as well as in wait_and_pop()). Furthermore i changed the ticket system to a queue of thread ids, but this is just a convenience, which keeps the source code compact. But I am not sure, if i want to use the queue in
production code, because i don't understand why it works now and i don't know if it works every case. Maybe someone can comment on this?

```
template <typename T>
class Tqueue 
{
public:
   void push(const T& e){
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
       m_queue.push(e);
       m_cond.notify_all();
   };

   T wait_and_pop() {
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
       m_ids.push(std::this_thread::get_id());
       m_cond.wait(lock,[=]{return (!m_queue.empty())
                  && (m_ids.front() == std::this_thread::get_id());});
       T data = m_queue.front();
       m_queue.pop();
       m_ids.pop();
       m_cond.notify_all();
       return data;
   }

private:
   std::queue<T> m_queue;
   std::queue<std::thread::id> m_ids;
   std::mutex m_mutex;
   std::condition_variable m_cond;

 };
```

Comment: excellent threading exercise :)

Comment: Note that you print after you are out of the critical section. Which means threads value will be printed in random order.

Comment: It works now because you make sure to wake threads any time you change shared data that a thread could be waiting for. Do you still have a version that doesn't work that you think should work? If so, update with that and someone will explain why it doesn't work. (By the way, do you really have a use case where fairness is preferred over performance? It's not like threads file union grievances.)

Comment: The bug was that you didn't call `notify_all` in `wait_and_pop`. In this case, it makes no difference whether you call `notify_all` from `push` with or without the lock, (except that calling it with the lock is slightly more efficient on most platforms).

Answer (score 2):

Notifications are indeed lost. It is possible that a number of `push` generate an even less number of threads being woke up because when `m_cond.notify_all();` is executed it just make waiting threads **runnable**, ie ready to run. These threads still have to wait their turn and acquire the lock inside `m_cond.wait`.

What is also possible is the fact that the main thread keep acquiring the mutex few more times before a **single** waiting thread can finally execute. Which cause the notification starvation.

In order to make the mechanism work, **you need to notify anytime the condition  is affected**. You already notify on `m_queue.push(e);`, which affect the first condition `!m_queue.empty()`. You also need to notify at the end of `wait_and_pop`, to take care of the second condition `ticket == m_counter`.

```
T wait_and_pop() {
   ....blah blah
   T data = m_queue.front();
   m_queue.pop();

   lock.unlock();
   m_cond.notify_all();
   return data;
}
```

**note:** By `it is possible` here I mean *"eventually there is a thread scheduling which eventually happen"*. I don't mean *" I am not sure"*.

**Further explanations :**
`condition_variable.notify_all()` only guarantees to wake up threads eventually. It doesnt guarantee that `X` number of calls will wake up `X` times. Furthermore, due to your condition, It is reduced to guarantee notifying only one thread, which is the root cause.

**About notifying before or after unlocking in wait_and_pop** 
It should not make any difference whether you notify before or after releasing the lock in `wait_and_pop`. The modification I specified should behave as the one in the edit. I have been making tests with few variations (thread count, waiting for x thread to finish and pushing again) with the same results.

Comment: While your suggested solution is an improvement, i still get deadlocks from time to time.And i still don't get it why i am losing notifications. But maybe i am just not smart enough. These multithread problems make my head hurt :)

Comment: to put it simply, `queue.push(i);` can generate 200 notifications, but threads wake up only once. This is the worst case and very unlikely but it is true. Due  the operating system scheduler deciding to keep the main thread running.

Comment: What happens if you notify when you are still holding the lock in wait_and_pop?

Comment: what happen if you push all first and wait later?

Comment: Thanks for the further explanations. When i push first and then wait everything works as expected. When i notify while still holding the lock, it seems to work. I am not sure because i tested this on another machine. I will retry it tomorrow.

Comment: Notifying while still holding the lock in both functions does the trick. At least as far as i say (see edit). Do you think this is stable and will never result in a deadlock?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88553/discussion-between-umnyobe-and-icepic).

Answer (score 0):

If only one of yours threads is started after you've started to push, it will be blocked forever.
You should try if queue is not empty first. Why wait if there are data already.

Comment: No actually i don't think so. When there is already one element in the queue the precondition is true and no blocking occurs.

Comment: You're right - with this it is working: m_cond.wait(lock, [=]{ return !m_queue.empty(); } );
but not anymore if I use also ticket + m_counter.